# Error 13: type mismatch for a textbox on userform where similar vba statement works

Tags: excel, vba

One of our spreadsheets requires a userform. When trying to paste the user's values to the sheet housing the data, I get error code 13: type mismatch.

All the fields are textboxes. One line of code identical except the address of where we're posting the information works.

Here's what I have:

```
Public Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim TableSht As Worksheet
Dim NextRow As Long

Set TableSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table")

TableSht.Visible = True

'https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1017033-making-all-fields-userform-mandatory.html#post4880848
'determine if any fields were left blank
For Each Control In Me.Controls                                     '
Select Case TypeName(Control)
    Case "TextBox"
        If Control.Value = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "empty field in " & Control.Name
            Exit For
        End If
     Case Else
End Select
Next Control

'data is housed in E3:J3, E5:J5, E7:J7, E9:J9. if statement determines what row information
'should be entered on.
If TableSht.Range("E3") = "" Then
NextRow = 3
    ElseIf TableSht.Range("E5") = "" Then
    NextRow = 5
        ElseIf TableSht.Range("E7") = "" Then
        NextRow = 7
            ElseIf TableSht.Range("E9") = "" Then
            NextRow = 9
                Else
                MsgBox ("There are no more available rows. Contact Craig for additional assistance.")
End If

'paste the user's data entry into the appropriate cells
With TableSht
.Cells(NextRow, 5) = Me.tbOwner
.Cells(NextRow, 6) = CDate(Me.tbDate)
.Cells(NextRow, 7) = Me.tbChange
'Me.tbChange.Value = CDec(Me.tbChange) 'no longer use this but one of my attempts

.Cells(NextRow, 8) = Me.tbAmount
.Cells(NextRow, 9) = Me.tbOriginal
.Cells(NextRow, 10) = Me.tbReason

.Cells(NextRow, 7).Value = Format(Range("G" & NextRow) / 100, "0.00%")
.Cells(NextRow, 8).Value = Format(Range("H" & NextRow), "$##.##")
.Cells(NextRow, 9).Value = Format(Range("I" & NextRow) / 100, "0.00%")
End With

Sheets("Rate Calculator v8").Select

TableSht.Visible = xlVeryHidden

Unload Me
End
End Sub
```

The error occurs on

```
.Cells(NextRow, 7).Value = Format(Range("G" & NextRow) / 100, "0.00%")
```

There's no error if I remove the line and cycle through the two after it, even though the last line before "end with" is essentially the same statement.

I've tried swapping the two lines of code that are similar. "Cells(NextRow, 7)..." and ".Cells(NextRow, 9)..." but the error still shows up on the "Cells(NextRow, 7)..." line.

I've confirmed the cells the data is pasted in columns G and I are both formatted as "percentage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qualify your `Range` usage with a sheet. If the sheet is also `TableSht`, the below should work. If the `Range` is from a different sheet, qualify that sheet

```
 = Format(.Range("G" & NextRow) / 100, "0.00%")
 = Format(.Range("H" & NextRow), "$##.##")
 = Format(.Range("I" & NextRow) / 100, "0.00%")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I thought because I had the "with tablesht" that this qualified the references. I suppose it was qualifying the first portion ".cells" but not the "Format(Range" portion. Makes sense now. Thank you so much!